# How do I create a SOAP front-end for my REST web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, apache-camel

For internal reasons I don't want to get into, I have to build REST web services for my project. For external reasons, I also need to build SOAP web services. Because of our architecture, my SOAP web services will have to call the REST web services to perform the functions.

So, let's just skip the part where you tell me that it's silly to run SOAP web services through our REST web services and talk about how I can get it done.

Someone said i could use Apache Camel for this, but I wanted to bounce it around first and see other recommendations if any.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any kind of modern SOA infrastructure?

Comment: Since i don't know what you mean, I'm going to guess no.

Answer (score 0):

If you built your rest services with cxfrs, you should be able to just add a soap endpoint using cxf.

your cxfrs endpoint

```
public class PlanningRestEndpoint implements PlanningEndpoint {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("plannings/before")
    @Override
    public List<Planning> findPlannings() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and your cxf endpoint

```
@WebService
public interface PlanningEndpoint {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "planning")
    List<Planning> findPlannings();
}
```

and add this endpoint to your route

```
from("cxf:bean:planningIn", "cxfrs:bean:planningRestIn")//
  .to(...)
```

Camel will do the job for you.

Comment: I think so. I was in the same situation as you and Camel worked like a charm.

Comment: @Thom what did you do finally?

Comment: Haven't yet. Still thinking about it. :)